# How to properly establish SSL connection from UWP App to WebAPI using HttpClient class?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, ssl-certificate, uwp, dotnet-httpclient

I have an UWP application which communicates with server WebAPI. To do this I am using HttpClient class from Windows.Web.Http namespace. It does work fine if I use simple Http URL. Because of sending passwords and other sesitive data I would like to use SSL. But the problem appears when I am trying to use Https URL. Program still shows me an error which says that "The certificate authority is invalid or incorrect". I am new in certificates etc. so it does not tell me anything useful.
On some websites I found some semi-solution. Using HttpBaseProtocolFilter class I can set options to ignore some server certificate errors like this:

```
HttpBaseProtocolFilter filter = new HttpBaseProtocolFilter();
filter.IgnorableServerCertificateErrors.Add(ChainValidationResult.Untrusted);
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(filter);
```

It works, but only on desktop. When I run my application on Mobile Emulator, the error shows up again. Also I do not really think that this is a good solution so I have searched for something else and just found this: https://pfelix.wordpress.com/2012/12/16/using-httpclient-with-ssltls/ . There are some informations about HttpClient and SSL, but as far as I understand it is about HttpClient from namespace System.Net.Http. I tried this solution for Windows Store App, but it have not worked too.

```
var client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler
    {
        ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Automatic
    });
```

So here is my question: how can I set up this HttpClient (from Windows.Web.Http or System.Net.Http) to perform working SSL connection with my WebAPI? Maybe is there something to set by server side?

**Edit:** I am using IIS Express from Visual Studio 2015 because I do not really know how to add my WebAPI to full IIS and let it work. I also turn on SSL in WebAPI project Properties, which generated for me a Https URL (so I thought that it would also generate a properly certificate). If I try to navigate to the Http URL everything is fine on my Mozilla Firefox and IE. The error about untrusted certificate shows when I try my https://localhost:44301/ URL in both browsers.

Comment: Using invalid SSL certificate does not really add much to securing connection... Getting valid SSL certificate matching host name you are using from trusted authority would be better approach (also not free).

Comment: So until I use the WebAPI on localhost (sorry that I did not mention it) the SSL connection will not work properly?

Comment: You really should start with having valid SSL certificate... If you need one on localhost - this search https://www.bing.com/search?q=ssl+certificate+for+localhost should give you links to walk-troughs. You also should [edit] your question to clearly specify what is working and what is not (i.e. if navigating with regular browser to that WebAPI https location does not show any errors/what errors)

Comment: I have edited my question where I have written about how it works now.

I have also read a lot of websites from your link and have tried differnt solutions. Very hopeful seems to be [this one](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WorkingWithSSLAtDevelopmentTimeIsEasierWithIISExpress.aspx). It has leped me to throw off the error from IE, but it still appears in Mozilla Firefox and of course by using HttpClient.

Answer (score 1):

You were close with the HttpClientHandler approach, but you want to trust the server certificate, not the client certificate (which doesn't exist in your example). Try this:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler { 
ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (a, b, c, d) => true });
```

This will cause ALL server certificates to  be trusted so don't use it in production, but works great for accessing an https service on localhost from a UWP app during development.